# Converting char array to uint16_t array C/C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, bit-shift, byte-shifting

I've written the below code to convert and store the data from a string (array of chars) called `str`into an array of 16-bit integers called `arr16bit`

The code works. However, i'd say that there's a better or cleaner way to implement this logic, using less variables etc.

I don't want to use index `i` to get the modulus % 2, because if using little endian, I have the same algorithm but `i` starts at the last index of the string and counts down instead of up. Any recommendations are appreciated.

```
// assuming str had already been initialised before this ..

int strLength        = CalculateStringLength(str);      // function implementation now shown 
uint16_t*  arr16bit  = new uint16_t[ (strLength /2) + 1];  // The only C++ feature used here , so I didn't want to tag it
int indexWrite       = 0;
int counter          = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < strLength; ++i)
{
    arr16bit[indexWrite] <<= 8;
    arr16bit[indexWrite] |= str[i];
    if ( (counter  % 2) != 0)
    {
        indexWrite++;
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: `new uint16_t( (strlen /2) + 1)` allocates memory for *one single* `uint16_t` value, and initializes that single value to `(strlen /2) + 1`

Comment: You don't have a specific problem but want suggestions on how to improve the code. So question is more suitable for [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Also, this is C++ code and not C code.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, you're right. I corrected it []

Comment: _"if using little endian, I have the same algorithm but i starts at the last index of the string and counts down instead of up."_ No it doesn't; only the bytes within each pair are swapped

Comment: Why do you have both `counter` and `i` which do exactly the same thing and always hold the same value? And why do you have `indexWrite` which is always exactly half (per integer division) of both of them?

Comment: `uint16_t*  arr16bit  = new uint16_t( (strlen /2) + 1);` - use `std::vector<uint16_t>`

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Because if I want to arrange the bytes the other way around in the u16 array, I have another algorithm which counts from strLength -1 backwards

Comment: You didn't state that in the question. So the whole problem is under-specified and nobody can help you.

Comment: Also `(strLength/2) + 1` is overallocating one element. It's better to allocate it only if it's needed `(strLength/2) + (strLength%2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are some redundant variables here.

You have both `counter` and `i` which do exactly the same thing and always hold the same value. And you have `indexWrite` which is always exactly half (per integer division) of both of them.

You're also shifting too far (16 bits rather than 8).

```
const std::size_t strLength = CalculateStringLength(str);
std::vector<uint16_t> arr16bit((strLength/2) + 1);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < strLength; ++i)
{
    arr16bit[i/2] <<= 8;
    arr16bit[i/2] |= str[i];
}
```

Though I'd probably do it more like this to avoid *N* redundant `|=` operations:

```
const std::size_t strLength = CalculateStringLength(str);
std::vector<uint16_t> arr16bit((strLength/2) + 1);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < strLength+1; i += 2)
{
    arr16bit[i/2]      = (str[i] << 8);
    arr16bit[(i/2)+1] |= str[i+1];
}
```

You may also wish to consider a simple `std::copy` over the whole dang buffer, if your endianness is right for it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I realise that I made a mistake and meant <<8 in my question and not <<16. I want to fit each two bytes into one ui16 variable. If reversing the endianess tho, i would start i at strLength -1 and decrement to zero, therefore the above logic would need to be changed a bit

Comment: @Engineer999 That's not what endianness is commonly understood to mean.